# How to design Joomla style plugin in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

First of all, I want to describe my project architecture:

1. My project uses jqGrid.
2. Controllers only define the Grid.
3. Then Models retrieve the Data for the Grid.
4. Models are used to Add/Edit/Delete Records.
5. Views are used to show the page.

Consider, I have 10 different kinds of customers for my project. My project is a hosted solution which serves my all 10 customers from a single source. Among them, eight needs the exact same as I created. Only two are different than the common.

For example, imagine that I want to show a product list. As my project is a hosted solution I can't change the menu by which I can change the controller for the said two customers.

To solve the problem, I want to implement plugin system like Joomla.

How can I do that in CodeIgniter?

### Edit

I am using CI 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help you:

There is module solution for Codeigniter [HMVC module](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) . It gives you way to divide application logic into modules with their own MVC structure (each module will have it's own model\view\controller).

After installing this module into CI you'll be able to call another module from main app's controller (or view or model) like that:

```
<?php echo modules::run('module/controller/method', $param, $...); ?>
```

So I think you can use modules functionality provided by this extension to build per customer modules structure based on customers roles.

Comment: I was forgotten to mention that I am using CodeIgniter 1.7.2 I found that HMVC is for CI 2.0  is this correct or wrong.

Comment: I'd just upgrade to CI2.0 if at all possible - numerous improvements, dropped PHP4 support. Might not be an option, of course.

Comment: Could you please give me a link of HMVC which can be used with CI 1.7.2 ? I can not upgrade right now because my office did not permit me to upgrade at the current stage of development. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, I see. They removed links to get 1.7 version, but in commits history at bitbucket seems that the last change before 1.7 support was removed is https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/changeset/2d6d33922276 . try to install it or search older commit. (in my case upgrading to CI 2.0 of large project took not so many efforts, but of course it differs from project to project)

Comment: see this how to for upgrade http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0

Comment: Ah. At last I am successful to get HMVC for CI 1.7.2 But there arises another issue. Consider that I have a module named modA and in that module I hava a Controller named conA. Then Please tell me the URI construction to call the conA controller remember that I have a lot of controllers outside the module and I can't change the project structure now.

Comment: if module's and controller's names are equal then url to call method will be like that `/controller/method`, but if they are not equal you'll need to add third part to url `/module/controller/method`

Comment: Thats nice. Thanks for helping me.